# How to resolve data confliction

Tags: java, php, database, database-design

I have several databases ,and need exchange data between them. When I export from db A import into db B, Id confliction will happen. I think out two approach, no one satisfy me.

1. select max(id) then create new id to avoid confliction ,but one column store json structure and contains id too! (history reason). So I need create new Id (primary key) and modify all ids in that json column.
2. or I can add a batch info for each data import. When I import data, I find out every id in sql and add batch id before them. Such as:

The original db like:

```
ID     COL_JSON
11     {id:11,name:xx ...}
```

I want to insert a new record :11 ,after insert I add a batch info "1000" before id

now db looks like

```
ID     COL_JSON
11     {id:11,name:xx ...}  
100011 {id:100011,name:xx ...}
```

the next batch will be 1001,1002 1003 ..., so if a new 11 record need to be insert the db looks like

```
ID     COL_JSON
11     {id:11,name:xx ...}  
100011 {id:100011,name:xx ...}  
100111 {id:100111,name:xx ...}
```

Although the two approach can resolve conflict, I feel the two approach is stupid. Is there some graceful scheme?

Comment: Are you talking about database synchronization approaches?

Comment: not sync question . I export data from Application A's DB and some files , then import to Application B (db & files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For legacy system, there is no better approach except to align with it. We cannot change it more on legacy system, so your 2th approach seems good. Frankly, tt's not stupid and just the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what your databases exchange.

If you need data from both databases in both of them you could use something similar to your batch but using characters - A11 and B11 ids.

This way you won't have conflicts even if your database grows a lot.

Edit: You could make also a primary key with two fields: the integer ID with autoincrement and a varchar for the original database name.

Comment: thanks reignerok. my problem is not just primary key conflict

Answer (score 0):

When I have a table that should be synchronized (not on the fly), I use this approach :

- The main table that will be overwritten has a big autoincrement (ie : autoincrement = 100000)
- The secondary table that will be merged to the main one has a normal autoincrement starting to 1.

**The only requirement is that you ensure that the main table has a big enough autocrement set up, so the secondary table id will never reach the main table first ID**